# Gamma function, a roadblock: $\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}\,dt = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^\infty e^{-u^{1/x}}\,du$?

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

In Spivak's *Calculus* 19 - 44, I'm being asked to prove that the previously encountered gamma function, defined as: $$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}\,dt$$
is equivalent to 
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^\infty e^{-u^{1/x}}\,du$$ 
with the use of the substitution 
$u=t^x$.
However I can't seem to get the lower limit of integration, $0$. 
Here's my argument:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1} \, dt=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}xt^{x-1} \, dt$$ 
let $g(x)=t^x$, $g'(x)=xt^{x-1}$, $f(u)=e^{u^{1/x}}$ and we get:
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_{g(0)}^{g(\infty)}e^{-u^{1/x}} \, du=\frac{1}{x} \int_1^\infty e^{-u^{1/x}} \, du$$
with the use of the substitution formula.
What am I missing? how do I get the 0?
Here's how the author does it:

Let $u=t^x$, $du=xt^{x-1} \, dt$. Then
\begin{align}
\Gamma(x)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1} \, dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-u^{1/x}}\frac{du}{x} \\
&=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^\infty e^{-u^{1/x}} \, du
\end{align}

But I don't understand how he can get away with not substituting the g function into the limits of integration, i feel stupid.
Thank you all in advance, even if I can't participate in this forum yet I want you to know that you've helped me a lot.

Simone

---

Edit: SOLVED! the argument of the $g$ function should be $t,$ not $x$!
Mind your "arguments", guys.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting tips.

Comment: thanks, i'll see if I can fix it. 5 min

Comment: Your main problem is that $g$ should be a function of $t$, not $x$.

Comment: 1. I can't believe you actually deciphered that thing: 2. that's it! I got confused with the argument, devilish Spivak!... thanks a lot!

Comment: Would it be rude to delete this? the didactic value of my question is null.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I've added the MathJax for the image. Try studying that by pressing the enter link and see if you can sort the rest out.

Comment: thank you Daniel, that actually helped a lot.

Comment: @simone, you'd be better off answering your own question than to delete this. Someone else may get stuck in the same way.

Comment: @Chickenmancer true, i'm formatting right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the point of error. The argument of the $g$ function should be $t$, not $x$.